# Express.js node.js syntax error trying to .update() mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

This works perfect

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body, req.body.uid)
    })
```

But then this throws a syntax error and crashed. My mongoDB is connected fine.

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    var myUid = req.body.uid;
    db.collection('users').update(
        {uid: myUid},
        req.body,
        {upsert: true},
    )
})
```

Help

Comment: You're missing a callback, or Promise resolution. See [`update()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#update) in the documentation. That alone should not be "throwing an error" though. So your "syntax error" is more likely along the lines of `db has no method collection`, or `db is undefined`, which is instead a problem related to scoping the `db` variable. Show the actual error or a full "minimal" listing to reproduce if you still don't understand what that means.

Comment: The syntax error might be from the trailing comma at the end of `{upsert: true},`. [Depends on your version of Node.js.](http://node.green/#ES2017-features-trailing-commas-in-function-syntax) (Note: If that's the cause, you should upgrade Node.js to at least [its current LTS](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you are facing is because you are trying to use dot notation as field in an object. Instead you should do this

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
  var myUid = req.body.uid;
  var myObjectBody = req.body;
  db.collection('users').update(
      {uid: myUid},
      myObjectBody,
      {upsert: true},
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Mongoose.js](http://mongoosejs.com/), this library makes your life easy.
With Mongoose.js, your code will turnout like this.

```
///// routes.js
import User from './model';
app.put('/users', (req, res) => {
    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.uid, req.body, {upsert:true, new:true})
    .then(updatedUser => res.json(updatedUser))
    .catch(err => next(err));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed req.body to an object

```
app.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    var myUid = req.body.uid;
    db.collection('users').update(
        {uid: myUid},
        {
         uid: req.body.uid
         name: req.body.name
         etc...
        },
        {upsert: true},
    )
})
```